# combining database tables in 3rd normal form

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have a relational database with 5 tables

```
1. student (Name, StudentID)
2. favorite_colorID (StudentID, ColorID)
3. favorite_collegeID (StudentID, CollegeID)
4. color (ColorID, Color)
5. college (CollegeID, College)
```

I want to come up with a query that prints out only `Name, Color, and College`

This might be a simple matter of JOINs but I haven't done serious queries for a year (lil rusty).

Comment: Do all students have a favorite color or college?  If not you'll need to use outer joins if you want to return records where a color or college is known but not both.  What about students who've not defined a color or college too?  Do you want them returned?  again if so, left outer joins.

Comment: for this example they all have a favorite color and a college. this is a (semi) simple example of inner joining database tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select s.name, c.color, co.college 
from student s inner join favorite_colorId fc on s.studentId = fc.studentId 
inner join color c on fc.colorId = c.colorId 
inner join favorite_collegeId fco on s.studentId = fco.studentId 
inner join college co on fco.collegeId = co.collegeId
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the foreign keys across the tables. Table student links to favorite_colorId and favorite_collegeID. When you inner join against those two based on a studentId you will recieve ColorId and CollegeId. Once you have both of those you can inner join against the table color and the table college.

```
student -> favorite_colorID -> color
student -> favorite_collegeID -> college
```

I don't want to give you the sql, but now that you know the paths I'm sure you can do it.